# "Save Graphic As..." suddenly doesn't work

Tags: plotting, warning-messages, printing, document-creation

I suddenly can't create jpegs or pngs using the menu.  I have not changed versions or operating systems lately, but the method I've used all along suddenly doesn't work.

When I create a plot, left-click on it, then right-click and choose "Save Graphics As..." a Message window pops up with the error message below. Restarting MMa and my computer did not help.

> 4/17/16 18:41:09  The specified setting for the option WindowSize
>   cannot be used.
>
> During evaluation of In[7]:= Set::shape: Lists 
>   {System`ConvertersDump`height$883,System`ConvertersDump`width$883} and
>   {0} are not the same shape. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[7]:= Image::imgarray: The specified argument
>   {} should be an array of rank 2 or 3 with machine-sized numbers. >>

Strangely, I can still use "Save Graphic As..." to create PDFs.

And Export[] still works:

```
Export["C:\Users\admin\Desktop\example.jpg", Plot[expr, {x, 0, 3}]]
```

The plot I was trying to save as a jpeg was generated by this code:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
gau[x_, v_] := Exp[-(x^2)/(2 v)]/Sqrt[2*Pi*v];
f[x_, m_, v_] = gau[x + m, v] + gau[x - m, v];
g[x_, m_, v_] = gau[x + m, v] - gau[x - m, v];
h[x_, m_, v_] := 2*Log[f[x, m, v]/f[0, m, v]] + (x^2)/v + 6 x*g[x, m, v]/f[x, m, v];
Plot[h[x, 3, 1], {x, 0, 3}]
```

And to emphasize, I'm doing this exactly the way I did it two days ago and for months before that, and this problem just started today.  Export[] gets the job done, but "Save Graphic As..." suddenly doesn't work right.

I am running MMa 10.3 on Windows 10.0.10586

Comment: It is cunningly prompting you to use PNGs, because nobody likes fuzzy graphs.

Comment: Please also provide the code used to `Export ` the plot.

Comment: @Bill, thanks for the help, but I didn't understand any of that.  I am not an advanced user.  Also, I didn't use Export.

Comment: @wxffles  Same problem when I tried PNGs.

Comment: @YvesKlett  I didn't use code.  I left-clicked the output plot, then right-clicked on it, and chose "Save Graphic As..."

Comment: Please add this information to the question to enable others to try to  reproduce your problem.

Comment: Which *Mathematica* version and what OS are you using? With version 10.4 on Windows 7 x64 and your code I get the expected JPG file without errors when I right-click on the plot and choose "Save Graphic As..."

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov  I've added the info.  This all worked fine for me a couple of days ago.  I suspect a bug.

Comment: @YvesKlett  I've added it. THanks.

Comment: Have you tried [How do I fix common problems by resetting Mathematica to its default configuration?](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464)

Answer (score 1):

**Code:**

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
gau[x_, v_] := Exp[-(x^2)/(2 v)]/Sqrt[2*Pi*v];
f[x_, m_, v_] = gau[x + m, v] + gau[x - m, v];
g[x_, m_, v_] = gau[x + m, v] - gau[x - m, v];
h[x_, m_, v_] := 2*Log[f[x, m, v]/f[0, m, v]] + (x^2)/v + 6 x*g[x, m, v]/f[x, m, v];
Plot[h[x, 3, 1], {x, 0, 3}]
```

**Example:**

*.png example

```
Export["example1.png",Plot[h[x, 3, 1], {x, 0, 3}]]
```

*.jpg example

```
Export["example2.jpg",Plot[h[x, 3, 1], {x, 0, 3}]]
```

**Output:**

*.png example:

[image: png example]

*.jpg example

[image: jpg example]

**Reference:**

[Export](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html)

**Tutorial:**

[Export Graphics](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/ExportGraphics.html)

Comment: I know about all this.  Export[] works fine.  It's "Save Graphic As..." on the menu that suddenly stopped working.